# Dynamic DBSet lookup and query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a partial result view that takes in the name of the table and a value for a particular column to query.  I read the DBContext API and found that Set(Type) should return a DBSet that you can do CRUD operations on. I don't know how exactly to query the DBSet without a PK since the user don't know the PK to look up.

May be using Classic ADO would be easier?

EDIT: I figure out how to use DbSet.SQLQuery function but have no clue to store the results.  I inspected the element in debugger and the SQLQuery does work as it found all the rows inside the table.

```
public class SF1DB : DbContext
{
    //List of table names that feeds a DropDownList
    public DbSet<tablelist> tables { get; set; }

    //Data table
    public DbSet<dataTable1> dataTable1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<dataTable2> dataTable2 { get; set; }
    //...list of other tables
}

public PartialViewResult GetFeatures(String tablelist, String[] countyfp)
{
    String type = "MvcApplication1.Models." + tablelist;
    Type dbType = Type.GetType(type);
    DbSet set = _db.Set(dbType);
    String sql = "select * from " + tablelist;

    //How do I store the result in a variable?
    set.SqlQuery(sql);
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish if you were not trying to make it dynamic?

Comment: I could use 40 if statements to figure out which table the user want to query and then query via the DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creating a List that have the same type as the DbSet that the user selected.  Then I use the SQLQuery's GetEnumerator method and iterate thru the result and add to the new list.  Finally, pass the list to the partial view.

```
public PartialViewResult GetFeatures(String tablelist, String[] countyfp)
{
    String type = "MvcApplication1.Models." + tablelist;
    Type dbType = Type.GetType(type);
    DbSet set = _db.Set(dbType);
    String sql = "select * from " + tablelist + " where ";
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(dbType);
    IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    for (int i = 0; i < countyfp.Length; i++)
    {
        sql += "cntyidfp like '%" + countyfp[i] + "'";
        if (i < (countyfp.Length - 1))
        {
            sql += " or ";
        }
    }

    IEnumerator result = set.SqlQuery(sql).GetEnumerator();
    while (result.MoveNext())
    {
        list.Add(result.Current);                
    }

    return PartialView(list);
}
```