# Razor view display domain model properties without knowing the domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**Background**: I have a simple mapping app (backed by GeoServer) that allow a user to click on a feature and select a data table displaying information about the selected feature.  A HTML table would then be inserted under the map to show the query results.

**Problem**: Since there are at least 40 something tables that the user can select, I don't want to build 40+ partial views.  Is it possible to build a Razor view that can handle any model passed to it and build a HTML table without knowing the domain model's structure?  I'm leaning toward no after some poking around.

**Reference**: Related to my previous question of 
[Dynamic DBSet lookup and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305796/dynamic-dbset-lookup-and-query)

Answer (score 1):

Practically, asp.net mvc already does that when you call `EditorForModel`, `DisplayForModel` or similar. If there is no developer defined view for corresponding model type, it calls object template, which uses reflection to render editor and display views. That template does not have predefined knowledge of model type.

You could set model type to object for view, and make use of reflection to generate tables.